# Reading only first 1 to 2 integers in a for loop VBA

Tags: vba, string

How do I read the first 1 to 2 integers of a string in a loop?  I need to only parse the first integer or the second integer. For example, "8sdr" I only want to parse "8" and then for a "12sdr" I want to parse "12".  I need this to be in a loop to be able to continuously parse only the first integers in a string.  Thank you!

Comment: The 8 is the first integer, and so is the 12. Did you mean up to two first digits?

Comment: use `VAL()`: `x = val("12sdr")` will return `12` to `x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will return any given number of digits from the start of a string:

```vb
Function LeadingDigits(text As String, maxDigits As Integer) As String
  Dim pos As Integer, c As String

  Do Until pos >= maxDigits Or pos >= Len(text)
    c = Mid$(text, pos + 1, 1)
    If c < "0" Or c > "9" Then Exit Do
    pos = pos + 1
  Loop

  LeadingDigits = Mid$(text, 1, pos)
End Function
```

Contrary to solutions that rely on `IsNumeric()` or `Val()`, this function does not get confused by strings that can be interpreted as numeric, but don't fall into the specification, such as

- hexadecimal (`"&habc"` = `2748`)
- scientific notation (`"3e4"` = `30000`)
- `+`/`-` signs at the start of the string
- decimal numbers `".5"` = `0.5`

Only decimal digits `0`–`9` at the start of the string are accepted.

The function returns a string, not a numeric type (like `Integer`) so that there can be a separate return value for "nothing found" (the empty string), and so that very long numbers can be returned that would not fit into a numeric data type.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only up to two numbers that occur before a letter I would use RegEx for this:

```
Public Function FirstTwoNumbersFromStringBeforeLetter(ByVal textNumbers As String) As Long
    Dim regEx
    Set regEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "[a-z].*|\D"
        FirstTwoNumbersFromStringBeforeLetter = Left(Val(.Replace(textNumbers, vbNullString)), 2)
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: `? FirstTwoDigits("&habc")` => `27`. `? FirstTwoDigits("3e1")` => `30`.

Comment: Would this work if the string is "8sdr35" or "12sdr35" only wanting to see either the 8 or the 12?

Comment: @ALeb For `8sdr35`, it will. For `8.3sdr5`, it won't.

Comment: Okay, for more complicated number extraction I would use RegEx, see my update.

Comment: With the regex `? numbersfromstring("12sdr35")` returns `1235` and not `12` like the OP wants.

Comment: Maybe you didn't read the whole post. There are two functions, the second calls the first.

Comment: `FirstTwoDigits = Val(Left(IIf(IsNumeric(Left(textNumbers, 1)), textNumbers, "AA"), 2))`

Comment: Except 83 would be the first two digits.

Comment: See the second comment, the OP wants only the digits before the first letter.

Comment: See new regex, it stops at the first letter now.